# Alfresco 5.0.c + SOLR4, custom properties not indexed

Tags: solr, alfresco, solr4

I'm using Alfresco 5.0.c. Recently I've upgraded from Solr 1.4 to Solr 4 (locally and on server).

The problem I've faced with is that custom properties are not indexed anymore.

In Solr 1.4 to index custom properties I was using `search.get.config.xml` file with following content:

```
<search>
  <default-operator>AND</default-operator>
  <default-query-template>
    %(cm:name cm:title cm:description
    <!--custom properties-->
    xz:personStatus xz:username xz:typeName xz:orgUnit xz:fullName 
    TEXT TAG)
  </default-query-template>
</search>
```

But it seems that for Solr 4 this approach doesn't work.

How I can tell Solr 4 to index custom properties?

Another related question.

I installed clean version of alfresco 5.0.c using maven sdk and found out that out of the box it uses solr 1.4 not solr 4 as it was advertized.
In pom.xml of solr artifact-id is `alfresco-solr` not `alfresco-solr4`.
Do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience I installed Alfresco community 5.0.c using the setup wizard and, as stated in the docs [Alfresco SolR4 installation and configuration](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/solr4-install-config.html)

> The Solr 4 search subsystem is installed by default when you install Alfresco One 5.0 using the setup wizards (installer)

I can assure you that my custom properties are successfully indexed.

Inspecting the Alfresco nexus repository I can see that the correct dependency for 5.0.c is `alfresco-solr`, whereas under the `org.apache.solr.apache-solr` branch there is a latest `1.4.1-alfrescopatched-20141112` dependency

For more info take a look here [Alfresco SDK 2.0.0](http://mindthegab.com/2014/12/24/alfresco-sdk-2-0-0-is-finally-out-merry-xmas-alfresco-devs/)